Не происходят изменения при вызове команды MVVM WPF
У меня есть окна WPF, имеющие следующий XAML код:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.ManagerWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary3;assembly=ClassLibrary3" 
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:DailyReportsModelView}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ManagerWindow" Height="450" Width="863">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Отчёты">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}" SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedReport}" Margin="0,0,429,0">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Locksmith}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListBox>

                    <StackPanel Background="#FFE5E5E5" DataContext ="{Binding SelectedReport}" Margin="428,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Выбранный элемент" FontSize="16"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="Количество деталей" FontSize="16" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding DetailsCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="16"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Дата" FontSize="16" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Date, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Работник" FontSize="16" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ComboBox 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Locksmiths}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocksmith, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Margin="430,133,3,226"/>
                    <Button Content="Добавить отчёт" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="465,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="365" FontSize="16" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Content="Сохрнаить текущий отчёт" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="465,203,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="365" FontSize="16"/>
                    <Button Content="Удалить выбранный отчёт" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="465,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="365" FontSize="16"/>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>

<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.AddReportWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary3;assembly=ClassLibrary3"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:DailyReportsModelView}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AddReportWindow" Height="226" Width="180">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Количество деталей" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="DetailsCount" Text="{Binding ReportToAdd.DetailsCount}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label Content="Дата отчёта" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ReportDate" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ReportToAdd.Date, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="16"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="LocksmithSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding Locksmiths}" SelectedItem="{Binding ReportToAdd.Locksmith, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="16"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ReportToAdd}" Content="Добавить" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,153,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="34" Width="159" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Также у меня есть ViewModel:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary3
{
    public class DailyReportsModelView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Report _selectedReport;
        private Locksmith _selectedLocksmith;
        private Report _reportToAdd;
        DAO dao = new DAO();

        public ObservableCollection<Report> Reports { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Locksmith> Locksmiths { get; set; }
        public Report SelectedReport
        {
            get { return _selectedReport; }
            set
            {
                _selectedLocksmith = Locksmiths.FirstOrDefault(x => value.Locksmith.Id == x.Id); ;
                _selectedReport = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedReport");
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedLocksmith");
            }
        }

        public Locksmith SelectedLocksmith
        {
            get { return _selectedLocksmith; }
            set
            {
                _selectedLocksmith = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedLocksmith");
            }
        }

        public Report ReportToAdd
        {
            get { return _reportToAdd;}
            set
            {
                _reportToAdd = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ReportToAdd");
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand addCommand;
        public RelayCommand AddCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return addCommand ??
                    (addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                    {
                        Report report = (Report)obj;
                        dao.InsertReport(report);
                        Reports = dao.GetReports();

                        SelectedReport = report;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Reports");
                    }));
            }
        }

        public DailyReportsModelView(Workshop workshop)
        {
            Reports = dao.GetReports();
            Locksmiths = dao.GetLocksmiths(workshopId: workshop.Id);
            ReportToAdd = new Report();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}

При попытке добавления Report в окне AddReportWindow, запись в бд происходит, однако обновление в ListBox в ManagerWindow нет

Эм, а какая у вас связь между окнами? Как окну задается DataContext, как окно открывается? Как передаются данные от одного окна в другое? В вопросе я просто вижу одну VM, но 2 окна, будто использующие эту одну VM, если это так (что странно), то опять-же, как задается DataContext...?

ObservableCollection уведомляет View о том, что элементы были добавлены в коллекцию, и о том, что элементы были удалены из коллекции. Но не сообщает о том, что коллекция была заменена. Вам нужно или менять элементы в коллекции с помощью методов Add и Remove, или явным образом сообщить об изменении всей коллекции вызвав OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Reports));
При этом обоим окнам в DataContext должен быть назначен один и тот же экземпляр DailyReportsModelView, что (как заметил @EvgeniyZ) странно. Для каждого View лучше делать свою ViewModel

Решил вопрос. Проблема была в том, что я в конструкторах view передавал DataContext новый объект viewModel. Один viewModel на два окна связан с тем, что у меня открывается новое окно для добавления записи, и при нажатии кнопки добавления в открывшемся окне, в старом окне должен обновиться список существующий записей и автоматически выбраться (SelectedItem) добавленная запись.
